# Usage of the word 'coordinate'

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Have a look at the context:

```
Contents
   |
   |--- 1. Fundamentals
   |          | 
   |          |--- 1. Browsers
   |          | 
   |          |--- 2. Servers
   |          | 
   |          |--- 3. Security
   |
   |--- 2. Introduction
   |          | 
   |          |--- 1. Lists
   |          | 
   |          |--- 2. Tables
   |          |          |
   |          |          |--- 1. Rows
   |          |          |
   |          |          |--- 2. Columns
   |          | 
   |          |--- 3. Forms
   |          | 
   |          |--- 4. Frames
   |
   |--- 3. Basics
   |          | 
   |          |--- 1. Arrays
   |          | 
   |          |--- 2. Functions
```

If I want to locate `Rows`, I can always say "Chapter 2: Part 2: Section 1". But,

1. what is a common noun for "Chapter 2: Part 2: Section 1", "Chapter 1: Part 2", etc.
2. if I want to use a small convention here and call (2,2,1) as a coordinate of `Rows` and similarly (2,2) as a coordinate of `Tables`, will the word 'coordinate' be appropriate here? If not what is the better word here?

Answer (score 1):

What you have presented is an **hierarchical tree** and each named location is a **node** on that tree connected by **edges**.

Your description of the **terminal node** *rows* is made up by listing each node on the **path ** along those edges from the **root** *Contents*.

If you reduce that description to a string of digits by omitting their descriptive labels, then it could still be called a path.

Answer (score 0):

`2.2` and `2.2.1`, togther with wordy forms such as "Chapter 2: Part 2: Section 1" are ***references***.

In fact, that's all "co-ordinates" are: references to a particular point.

Comment: Or to be more specific, _co_-ordinate would normally be used to imply a position on a system having _multiple_ axes, so would not really be appropriate for this structure.